# Java Decimal Format results with trailing zeros

Tags: java, decimalformat

This is my code:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class asd {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DecimalFormat d = new DecimalFormat("#00.00");
        System.out.println(d.format(0250));
    }
}
```

It gives `168.00` as answer. This isn't the answer I was expecting (which is 250.00). Why is the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the leading `0` in `0250` makes it octal. Remove the leading `0`. Like,

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    DecimalFormat d = new DecimalFormat("#00.00");
    System.out.println(d.format(250));
}
```

See also [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/221797/reasoning-behind-the-syntax-of-octal-notation-in-java) for more on why that's the syntax for octal notation.

Comment: plus one for the link